# Xor Equality (codechef may 21 challenge )I am getting wrong results for some values like n=4589 any help is appreciated :)

Tags: c++, xor, modulo

/*For a given N, find the number of ways to choose an integer x from the range [0,2N−1] such that x⊕(x+1)=(x+2)⊕(x+3), where ⊕ denotes the bitwise XOR operator.

Since the number of valid x can be large, output it modulo 109+7.*/

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#define ll long long

const ll N = 1e5;      //user can input n upto 1e5
unsigned ll  arr[N];
unsigned ll p = 1e9 + 7;  // we have to find answer modulo p

ll mod_pow(ll a, ll b)
{
    if (b == 1)
    {
        return a;
    }
    ll   c   =   1;
    if  ( b % 2 == 0)
      c= ( mod_pow ( a  , b / 2) ) % p ; 
    else
    {
        c = ( mod_pow(a, (b - 1) / 2)) % p;
        return ((a % p) * c * c) % p;
    }
    return (c * c)%p;
}


 void pre()
{
    for ( unsigned ll i = 0;i < N;i++)
    {
        arr[i] = ( ( ( ( mod_pow ( 2, i+1) -1 + p ) %p ) * 1/2 ) %p + 1 ) %p;  
                                                  
                       / / precomputing for all even number in (2^n -1) 
    }

}
int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);cin.tie(NULL);
    pre();
    int t;
    cin >> t;

while (t--)
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << (arr[n-1])<<endl ;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to the problem? And explain what algorithm you are using.

Comment: https://www.codechef.com/MAY21C/problems/XOREQUAL

Comment: AS IT IS POSSIBLE ONLY FOR EVEN NUMBERS I WAS TRYING TO CALCULATE ((2^N)-1)/2 %1e9+7   +1 as 0 is also included .

Comment: I was getting right answer for most of test cases but it is not satisfying some test cases one i found was 4589 i.e n =4589/

Comment: You are taking the modulo , then divide by 2 then take the modulo. It might be wrong. More safe to use `1/2 = (p+1)/2 mod p`

Comment: i tried replacing but it is still giving me same results

Comment: it is also giving me warning    ----- warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'double' to 'unsigned __int64', possible loss of data

Comment: could it be the reason for bad output

Comment: I don't seen any `double`... yes it can give bad results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In practice, the solution is simply a power of two: `answer = 2^{n-1}`.

For efficiency, this implies that it is better to first calculate all solutions iteratively:

```
powerof2[n] = (2 * powerof2[n-1]) % p
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>

constexpr int N = 1e5;      //user can input n up to 1e5
unsigned long long  arr[N];
constexpr unsigned int p = 1e9 + 7;  // we have to find answer modulo p

//  pre-compute the powers of 2
 void pre() {
    arr[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        arr[i] = (2 * arr[i-1]) % p;  
    }
}

int main() {
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    pre();
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;

    while (t--) {
        int n;
        std::cin >> n;
        std::cout << arr[n-1] << std::endl ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```